# Chrome does not recognize height for SELECT option (Both jQuery & CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am unable to set height for select options with css or jQuery in chrome browser , while the same piece of code works in Firefox without any issue.

**CSS**

```
#select-jqry option{
    height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id='select-jqry'>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

Even I tried with jQuery,

```
$('#select-jqry option').css('height','50px');
```

**EDIT :** *Even Padding not working*

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/8Ab78/3/)

Comment: -1 why ? Is their anything wrong with this question. If already having a solution please provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Chrome, according to the [electric toolbox](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-optgroup-option-css-chrome/)

Answer (score 0):

Set `height` for `option` is not a valid behavior of CSS. If you really want to personalize your dropbox I recommend you to use this kind of libraries : http://bashooka.com/coding/9-useful-jquery-select-box-manipulation-plugins/

Personnaly I use DropKick and render are compatible with all browser and very customizable.

Comment: even padding not working , so what is the solution ?

Comment: Select (as input file) are very limited, it is just not possible.