# Unable to change drop down list's option height in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html.dropdownlistfor

```
<select id="organiser" name="organiser" onclick="dropDownOrganiser(this)">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="ca" >California</option>
    <option value="co" >Colorado</option>
    <option value="cn" >Connecticut </option>\
</select>

#organiser option{
    height:70px;   
    padding:25px 0;    
}
#organiser{
    height:50px;       
}
```

I am trying to change the height of options in select but it remains the same.I even tried padding but it didnt work.I need help regarding this.Otherwise suggest me some website for best drop down list designs?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the height the options. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807757/chrome-does-not-recognize-height-for-select-option-both-jquery-css

Comment: Select tags are hard to style, which is why so many plugins/scripts exist to change them for other markup. Let google be your friend

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to style dropdown options that works in most current popular browsers. The best way to do this is to create **custom dropdown list** with html, css and javascript.

You can find the tutorial as well as demo there: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

I find this tutorial is easy to understand and you can make your own dropdown list by reading this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add CSS for option of select box. But can using custom one like jquery plugin, or just custom html and css

Btw you can make the text bigger so that the select box will be bigger too.

Answer (score 0):

At last i found the best plugin for drop down lists.Bootstrap by silvio mortiro is user friendly and has keyboard navigations all well. Check http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/